# Recommendation for Jquery Calendar plugin with multiple months displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, calendar

I'm looking for a way to display multiple months and allow the user to select a date range across those months by clicking and dragging their mouse.
As you may know, looking for jQuery plugins (a plugin would be best at this point due to time constraints) can bring back mixed results and it's tough to know which one to trust.
All that to say, can anyone recommend a quality plugin which offers the functionality I've described?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-numberOfMonths) earlier and found it very flexible.

You can try [this](http://www.webappers.com/2010/06/08/wdcalendar-jquery-based-google-calendar-clone/). But it will not display multiple months.

[This one](http://www.overset.com/2008/05/12/multiday-calendar-datepicker-jquery-plugin/) allows multiple months display but does not allow drag-support.

[Timeframe](http://stephencelis.github.com/timeframe/) allows you to drag select multiple months display.

Comment: I saw that, and it looked good except I didn't see any out of the box click and drag selection ability.

Comment: Timeframe seems to be just what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has a simple 2 click selection much like the Google Analytics calendar works

http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

```
$('#date3').DatePicker({
    flat: true,
    date: ['2011-07-28','2011-07-31'],
    current: '2011-07-31',
    calendars: 3,
    mode: 'range',
    starts: 1
});
```